# Tkinter login page layout problem - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-menu

I'm trying to create a login page in Tkinter with `.pack()`. I wold like to place the `loginFrame` at the center of the small window. And inside the `loginFrame`, the username section on top of the password section.

```
def main():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("400x200")
    window.title("PySploit")
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.configure(background="#E1E5F2")

    loginFrame = tk.Frame(window).pack(anchor="center")

    usernameFrame = tk.Frame(loginFrame).pack(side=LEFT)
    passwordFrame = tk.Frame(loginFrame).pack(side=LEFT)

    tk.Label(usernameFrame, text="Username").pack(side=LEFT)
    tk.Entry(usernameFrame, name="username").pack(side=LEFT)

    tk.Label(passwordFrame, text="Password").pack(side=LEFT)
    tk.Entry(passwordFrame, name="password").pack(side=LEFT)
    
    window.mainloop()
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is my wrong output:

[image: This is my output]

Comment: Note that `loginFrame`, `usernameFrame` and `passwordFrame` are `None` due to the issue of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name). So those labels and entries are in the root window actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you don't need `usernameFrame` and `passwordFrame`, just `loginFrame` is enough.

You can put `loginFrame` at the center of the window using `place()` instead and put those labels and buttons inside `loginFrame` using `grid()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry("400x200")
    window.title("PySploit")
    window.resizable(False, False)
    window.configure(background="#E1E5F2")

    loginFrame = tk.Frame(window)
    # place loginFrame at the center of window
    loginFrame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')

    # use grid() instead of pack() to lay out labels and entries
    tk.Label(loginFrame, text="Username").grid(row=0, column=0)
    tk.Entry(loginFrame, name="username").grid(row=0, column=1)

    tk.Label(loginFrame, text="Password").grid(row=1, column=0)
    tk.Entry(loginFrame, name="password").grid(row=1, column=1)

    window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```